# Nginx custom 404 page fails when in a higher directory

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

I am trying to create a custom 404 page with Nginx. My nginx.conf file looks like this:

```
http {
    server {
        location / {
            root /nginx/html;
        }

        error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
        location = /custom_404.html {
            root /nginx/html;
            internal;
        }
    }
}
```

When I check with a URL like "/page_that_doesnt_exist", it works fine.

But if I add a trailing "/", eg "/page_that_doesnt_exist/" or "/page_that_doesnt_exist/and_more_stuff" it fails, returning a blank screen (not the default nginx 404 page).

When I check the server messages, it tells me the following:

```
"GET /page_that_doesnt_exist/ HTTP/1.1" 404 280 "-" 

[error] 6#6: *3 open() "/nginx/html/page_that_doesnt_exist/error404.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /page_that_doesnt_exist/error404.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/page_that_doesnt_exist/"

"GET /page_that_doesnt_exist/error404.js HTTP/1.1" 404 280 "http://localhost:8080/page_that_doesnt_exist/"
```

Which I take to mean that instead of nginx searching for my "custom_404.html" file in my "nginx/html" folder, it is adding "page_that_doesnt_exist" to the directory. Thus it now searches in "nginx/html/page_that_doesnt_exist/" and doesn't find a "custom_404.html" file in that directory.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like the `custom_404.html` document is using relative-path URIs to load it's resource files. You need to use `src="/error404.js"` with a leading `/` to make the URI absolute-path.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks! This worked.